# How to remove irrelevant history when splitting a repo?

Tags: git

I have a repository in which, at some point, a directory was added. Initially it looked like this directory would live with this repo but finally I decided to extract it into its own repo, independent of the first one.

I did this [according to GitHub instructions](https://help.github.com/en/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository). The extraction was a success, I was left with only the directory I needed.

When looking at the git history, I see that the part which is not relevant to that specific directory is still there:

[image]

The directory was initially added with the *"added alerting module"* commit (first one at the bottom of the yellow area):

- the red line on the left reflects commits which were done to files within this directory
- the gray one - on other files (which were removed during the successful extraction above).

**Is it possible to get rid of the "gray" commits (ending up on the branch `original/refs/heads/master`)?**

This is not a critical need - I can live with that part being dragged forever (and not updated in this repo) but for mostly aesthetical reasons I would be glad to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use git filter-branch just like you did it to get the result the other way round. Just replace `subdirectory-filter` (which means "only keep specified directory") with `index-filter` (which means "do something with the index before each commit").

To specify the "something" in "do something", index-filter takes as parameter a bash command which should modify the git index. In your case, the command should simply delete the unwanted directory.  For example:

```
--index-filter 'git rm -r -q --cached --ignore-unmatch the/unwanted/directory'
```

Leave everything else just you had it when extracting the directory.

Alternatively, take a look at filter-branch-docs. It has a bunch of options.